# upload apk error file name should be in format com.example

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Hi I am new to android and trying to publish on Google play first time.
I am getting error when uploading apk file saying file name should be in format com.example.myapp.apk
my package  name is  androidapplication1.androidapplication1.apk
there is no com in it!
is this the source of issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`androidapplication1.androidapplication1.apk` sounds like the file name of your application, not its package name. An apk file name shouldn't have more than one dot in it I believe.

The package name on the other hand should have multiple dots. The package name can be found in your manifest xml file. What does it say for that one?

Comment: thanks; quick question: so my package name should be something like

Comment: in xamarin studio i select project>publish android application; then  after

Comment: in xamarin studio i select project>publish android application; then  after entering  keystore    and in the next window  I changed the file name from androidapplication1.androidapplication1 to com.google.xxxx and the package was created successfully. however when i checked the package name  in obj\release android manifest.xml  ;i found it is not changed from androidapplication1.androidapplication1   so i made this change in the manifest file; still i get the same error when i try to upload it

Comment: I'm afraid, I'm not familiar with Xamarin Studio at all. The only thing I can tell you is that you're not allowed to use com.google.xxxx as a package name. android.blahblah and com.google.blahblah are reserved only for the use of Google. Please pick a unique package name for yourself (that is not likely to be used by anyone else, take the time to do this correctly the first time). Once you change a package name, note that you must rebuild, repackage, and recompile the application afterwards, otherwise it won't work. Also, a package name shouldn't have an .apk in it. That's for the file name.

Comment: Again, I think you're confusing the filename of your application with the package name of your application. The filename of your application really does not matter, so better not change its default value, and introduce errors in it. However, you must change the package name before you compile and publish an application. So do that part over, clear the cache, rebuild everything from scratch, correct all the possible errors this package name change could have triggered in the rest of your code base. Perhaps Xamarin will correct all those errors itself? In any case, recompile everything afterward

Comment: problem solved  by using  com.myebsiteaddress.myappname; com.google is restricted and cannot be used

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package)Taken from the developer site:

> A full Java-language-style package name for the application. The name should be unique. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, individual package name parts may only start with letters.
> To avoid conflicts with other developers, you should use Internet domain ownership as the basis for your package names (in reverse). For example, applications published by Google start with com.google. You should also never use the com.example namespace when publishing your applications.
>
> The package name serves as a unique identifier for the application.
> It's also the default name for the application process (see the
>  element's process process attribute) and the default
> task affinity of an activity (see the  element's
> taskAffinity attribute).
>
> Caution: Once you publish your application, you cannot change the
> package name. The package name defines your application's identity, so
> if you change it, then it is considered to be a differen
> t application and users of the previous version cannot update to the new version.

I created a sample app in my own development server with your package name androidapplication1.androidapplication1.apk . I didnot receive any errors. So you can either ask google for this issue or ensure that this package is not used by anyone in the play store.